# How to get values from a variable of type *sql.Rows in the view?

Tags: mysql, templates, go, web-deployment

In `posts` table, there are attributes like `title`, `content`.
I can get data of type `*sql.Rows` and pass them to the view by

```
 posts, err := db.Query("SELECT id, title FROM posts WHERE id = 1")
```

and

```
  err = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", posts)
```

but I couldn't display the `title` value in the view. Here is my code.

**index.go**

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "database/sql"
  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:****@/database")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
  defer db.Close()

  posts, err := db.Query("SELECT id, title FROM posts WHERE id = 1")
  var id int
  var title string
  for posts.Next() {
    err = posts.Scan(&id, &title)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err.Error())
    }
  }

  fmt.Println(posts)

  defer posts.Close()

  err = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", posts)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
  }
}
```

**index.gohtml**

```
  <h1>Awesome Posts</h1>

  {{$posts := .}}
  <p>{{$posts}}</p>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be passing `posts` to your template--you should pass a proper context struct, which contains your `id` and `title` values somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code and I think you have misunderstood how to extract data using the `sql` package.

As Flimzy said in the comments, you should pass a proper context struct which contains your ID and Title values somewhere.

If you check the [docs for sql.Rows](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows) you will see how to extract the data at each of the rows from your query...and in fact you already know how to get the rows and column values - by using the `Next()` and `Scan()` methods. But this should not be done by code in the HTML template, it should store the results in some variable which is passed to the template.

### Quick Answer

A quick answer to your question would be to change how you pass the values into the template and amend the template. Seeing as you declare `id` and `title` variables you should pass them to the template:

```
err = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", map[string]interface{}{"ID": id,"Title": title})
if err != nil {
  log.Println(err)
}


<h1>Awesome Posts</h1>
<p>{{.ID}} - {{.Title}}</p>
```

### Having a Post model

A better solution would be to have a struct which holds all of the properties of the post, and use this to `Scan` into.

```
type Post struct{
  ID int
  Title string
}

...
var p Post
...
_ = rows.Scan(&p)
```

However, there is another problem with the way you are storing the results of the query. You are using `db.Query` to return a single row - *This is an assumption as you have `WHERE ID=1`*. If you expect only one post to be returned then use the QueryRow method:  (*N.B.* you can chain on the Scan method for simplicity)

```
var p Post
// error handling removed for brevity
_ = db.QueryRow("SELECT id, title FROM posts WHERE id = 1").Scan(&p)
_ = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", p)
```

If, however, you are expecting to retrieve multiple posts (and you were just adding the where clause for simplicity), then you need to `Scan` into a `Post` struct, and append into a slice of `Posts`.

```
rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT id, title FROM posts")
defer rows.Close()
var posts []Post
for rows.Next() {
  var p Post
  _ = posts.Scan(&id, &p) // you should handle error here.
  posts = append(posts, p)
}
if err = tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", posts); err!=nil{
  log.Println(err)
}
```

### Other considerations

You should not be creating a connection to the DB within the HTTP handler. One way is to have a global variable which holds the connection. A struct with embedded connection can work and/or it is possible to abstract away the connection into a package as well.

**/db/db.go**

```
package db

import (
    "database/sql"
    // MYSQL driver
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

var db *sql.DB

// Open handles the opening of the DB
func Open(connstr string) (err error) {
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", connstr)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    return nil
}

// Close handles the closing of the DB
func Close() error {
    return db.Close()
}
```

**/db/posts.go**

```
package db

// Post model
type Post struct {
    ID    uint
    Title string
    Body  string
}

const (
    getPosts = `SELECT id, title, body FROM posts`
    getAPost = `SELECT id, title, body FROM posts WHERE id=?`
)

// GetPosts will return all posts from the DB
func GetPosts() ([]Post, error) {
    rows, err := db.Query(getPosts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var posts []Post
    for rows.Next() {
        var p Post
        if err := rows.Scan(&p.ID, &p.Title, &p.Body); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        posts = append(posts, p)
    }

    return posts, nil
}

// GetPost will return single post identified by ID from the DB
func GetPost(id uint) (Post, error) {
    var p Post
    if err := db.QueryRow(getAPost, id).Scan(&p.ID, &p.Title, &p.Body); err != nil {
        return p, err
    }
    return p, nil
}
```

**main.go**

```
import (
    "chilledoj/sopost/db" // this is the absolute path to the db folder 
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "flag"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var dbconn string

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&dbconn, "dbconn", "", "MYSQL DB Connection string")
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {

    if dbconn == "" {
        log.Fatal("DB Connection string not set")
    }

    if err := db.Open(dbconn); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    r := mux.NewRouter()    

    r.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler())
    r.HandleFunc("/posts", postsHandler())
    r.HandleFunc("/posts/{id}", postHandler())

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}

var indexHandler = func() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.URL.Path != "/" {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(`<h1>Welcome</h1><a href="/posts">Posts</a>`))
    }
}

var postsHandler = func() http.HandlerFunc {
    tmpl, err := template.New("posts").Parse(`<h1>Awesome Posts</h1>
  <ul>{{range .}}
  <li><a href="/posts/{{.ID}}">{{.Title}}</a></li>
  {{end}}</ul>
  <hr/>
  <a href="/">Home</a>`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        posts, err := db.GetPosts()
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
            return
        }
        err = tmpl.Execute(w, posts)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("There was a template Error.\n%v\n", err)
        }
    }
}

var postHandler = func() http.HandlerFunc {
    tmpl, err := template.New("posts").Parse(`<h1>Awesome Posts</h1>
  <h2>{{.Title}}</h2>
  <p>{{.Body}}</p>
  <hr/>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/posts">Posts</a>`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        vars := mux.Vars(r)
        id, err := strconv.ParseInt(vars["id"], 10, 32)
        if err != nil {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        post, err := db.GetPost(uint(id))
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
            return
        }
        tmpl.Execute(w, post)
    }
}
```

Run the above using

```
go run main.go -dbconn [dbuser]:[dbpass]@/[dbname]?parseTime=true
```

Another way is to use dependency injection and have a function take in a db connection but return an `http.HandlerFunc`. e.g.

```
var indexHandler = function (db *sql.DB) http.HandlerFunc{
  return function(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    // now have access to db
  }
}

http.HandleFunc("/posts", indexHandler())
```

Comment: I get "db declared and not used" from ```/db/db.go``` ...
I made the variable Global by renaming it to ```DB``` but it doesn't solve

Comment: I've expanded the example with full code which is working for me.